# Address bar auto-suggestions---How to show the webpage address first, not the webpage title?

Tags: google-chrome

In Google chrome, when I start typing in the address/search bar, the auto-suggestions that are shown below are in this format:

```
[website title][website address]
```

But previously it was

```
[website address][website title]
```

So if I start typing "prom", it shows up

```
FAQ Prometheus https://prometheus.io/docs/introduc....
Grafana Prometheus Stats http://localhost:3000/dashboard/db....
```

But as I am used to select based on the address and not title, now it has become a lot tedious for me to find the exact address  I am looking for(as it is not in the start of the line and instead in a random middle place)

Any way to revert back to [website address][website title] format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the time being, you can adjust this via `chrome://flags/#omnibox-ui-swap-title-and-url`.

Change the "Omnibox UI Swap Title and URL" flag to "Disabled".

Comment: Great, working! But why "for the time being"? is it not permanent?

Comment: I don't know. Some feature flags in Chrome stay forever, others only exist through 2-3 releases.